# javafx: Custom TableColumn

Tags: javafx, autocomplete, tablecolumn

I want to make a custom `TableColumn` that when in editable state it's cells will be auto complete `TextField`s, here is what I tried:

```
public static <T,S> void setAutoCompleteTableColumn(TableColumn<T,S> column, List items){
    column.setCellFactory(param -> {
        return new TableCell<T, S>(){
            final TextField textField = new TextField();

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(S item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if(item == null){
                    setGraphic(null);
                }else {

                    setGraphic(textField);
                    AutoCompletionBinding<T> binding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField,items);
                    binding.setOnAutoCompleted(event ->{
                        //handleCompleted.accept(event.getCompletion());
                    });
                }

            }
        };
    });
}
```

This code have produced (obviously) this:

[image]

But I want this form only when the TableView is in edit mode, So I did this instead:

```
public static <T,S> void setAutoCompleteTableColumn(TableColumn<T,S> column, List items){
    column.setCellFactory(param -> {
        return new TableCell<T, S>(){
            final TextField textField = new TextField();

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(S item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if(item == null){
                    setGraphic(null);
                }else {
                    editableProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue)->{
                        if(newValue){
                            setGraphic(textField);
                        }else{
                            setText(item.toString());
                        }
                    });

                    AutoCompletionBinding<T> binding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField,items);
                    binding.setOnAutoCompleted(event ->{
                        //handleCompleted.accept(event.getCompletion());
                    });
                }

            }
        };
    });


}
```

As you can see I added a listener to `editableProperty`, which resulted in nothing. 
What I want is an editable TableColumn like in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm), but  with auto complete `TextField`. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean you want the text field to only be displayed when the cell is being edited (i.e. after the user double-clicks it), and a label at other times?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: In the link you provided, example 12-11 shows the implementation of a table cell that does exactly that: it shows a text field in "editing mode" and a label otherwise. Use that as a template: the two differences are that you shouldn't use the `focusedProperty()` to commit an edit (that no longer works, long story), so use `setOnAction()` on the text field and commit the edit there; and of course you will want to bind the auto complete on the text field you create. The `editable` property you are referencing determines if editing is allowed, not if the cell is in editing mode.