# Javafx: Table Column commit on Button click

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have method that make a `TableColumn` editable that I made according to this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm), with the two changes recommended in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678347/javafx-custom-tablecolumn?noredirect=1#comment70554195_41678347) witch are changing `focusedProperty` with `setOnAction` and add binding. The method is like this:

```
public static <T> void setAutoCompleteTableColumn(TableColumn<T,String> column, BiConsumer<T, String> field, String type, BiConsumer handleUpdates, List autoComplete){
    column.setCellFactory(param -> {
        return new TableCell<T, String>(){
            private TextField textField;

            @Override
            public void startEdit() {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelEdit() {
                super.cancelEdit();
                setText((String) getItem());
                setGraphic(null);
            }


            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {

                    if (isEditing()) {
                        if (textField != null) {
                            textField.setText(getString());
                        }
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(textField);
                    } else {
                        setText(getString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void createTextField(){
                textField = new TextField(getString());
                textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
                textField.setOnAction(event ->{
                    if(textField.getText() != ""){
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
                });

                AutoCompletionBinding<T> binding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField,autoComplete);
            }

            private String getString() {
                return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
            }
        };
    });
    column.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        T model = event.getRowValue();
        if (!event.getNewValue().isEmpty()) {
            Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
            final T oldModel = cloner.deepClone(model);
            
            //Update the old value with the new value
            field.accept(model, event.getNewValue());

            //Retrieve changes
            handleUpdates.accept(oldModel, model);
        }
    });

}
```

I use this method in the controller like this:

```
TableColumn<Purchase, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>();
setAutoCompleteTableColumn(nameColumn, (p,s) -> validatePurchaseEdit(p,s), "text", (o, n) -> updateTracker(o, n), appState.items);
```

I have a button click event that switch the `TableView` editable to false.
For some reason when this event is executed the current cell that I am editing does commit edit but an other cell(a random one) switches to edit mode. Can some one explain what is happening, and how can I make all cells commit edit?

Comment: `textField.getText() != ""` this is a bad idea. It's not guarantied that the text values are interned and strings should be compared using `equals` unless you know the strings are both interned. (In this case `!textField.getText().isEmpty()` should do the trick...)

Comment: Ok I just changed it but the problem still exists.

Comment: It would be nice if you post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have found a better implementation made in this link https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357#file-editcell-java-L109